Why is there no syntax highlighting for CSS in Vs Code, with the GitHub Dark Default theme applied?
I've been using the GitHub dark default theme in Vs Code for quite a while now. I'm now learning CSS and I've noticed that there is no syntax highlighting with the theme with a .CSS file.
I've tried changing themes and all other themes have syntax highlighting for CSS. Is there a setting I can change to enable it? or a script in the settings.json file that will enable it? I've attached some images for reference.
CSS - Github Dark Default
CSS - Vs Code Dark Modern
Python - Github Dark Default

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?
